# Custom Flutter Android FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: flutter, kotlin, flutter-android

I'm trying to make a custom FirebaseMessagingService in Android for Flutter to execute Kotlin code on receiving a notification in the background. Does anyone have an example of how this can be done while still receiving the `notification`/`message.data` in the main flutter app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a custom flutter plugin that is run in the background using the `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundMessageHandler);`